# 複数の外部キーを持つテーブルをcakephpのアソシエーション機能で結合したい

Tags: php, cakephp

【環境】
　　PHP 5.3.19
　　Cakephp 2.6.1

下記のように、外部キーが複数あった場合にアソシエーションすることはできるのでしょうか？

```
【hoge_oneテーブル】
id,
foreign_code_1,
foreign_code_2,
date,


【hoge_manyテーブル】
id,
foreign_code_1,
foreign_code_2,
hoge,
data,
etc

   ※hoge_manyテーブルとhoge_oneをつなぐ結合キーは
      foreign_code_1, foreign_code_2だけになります。（外部キーの追加はなし）
   ※hoge_one から hoge_manyに対して、hasmanyでアソシエーションを行いたい。
```

よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 2):

```
public $hasMany = array(
    'HogeMany' => array(
        'foreignKey' => 'foreign_code_1',
        'conditions' => array('HogeMany.foreign_code_2' => 'HogeOne'.foreign_code_2),
    )
);
```